# Is there a way to download an andorid emulator in Macbook air with M1 chip

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, macos-big-sur

I am trying to set up my Macbook air with M1 Chip for mobile app development, the problem is when I am trying to download an android emulator through android studio it keeps on failing so I am beginning to think there is something I am not doing right, Even when I download the android emulator manually it won't open up.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's been a while, I'd like to attach the link here just for others' convenience.

Google released an emulator for Mac M1, but only in preview mode. You can download it here: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases/tag/0.2